# Oracle SQL PIVOT Table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table

What I have is a query, where I am selecting locations, counts, etc.
Here is my query: And, I am trying to basically PIVOT the tables I believe. I have looked into PIVOT and such, but it doesn't seem like there is a clear cut way to do it. If any help can be guided would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated Query to include type and MT0 Suggestion**

```
 WITH qry AS (
select Floor, 
"Mod", 
Count_Type, 
Remaining_Counts, 
Location, 
Floor || '' || "Mod" || '' || Count_Type || '' ||  Location as "Unique"
from
(
select bin_level as Floor, bin_module as "Mod", icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_property_value as Count_Type, count(icqa_processes.icqa_process_id) as Remaining_Counts, 
CASE when bin_type_name = '14-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')  
     when bin_type_name = '18-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
     when bin_type_name = '24-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
     when bin_type_name = '30-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
     when bin_type_name = '34-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')  
     when bin_type_name = '48-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
     when bin_type_name = '48-KIVA-XL' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
     when bin_type_name = '78-KIVA-TALL' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
     when bin_type_name = 'PALLET-SINGLE' and usage = '1024' then ('KIVA-PALLET')  
     else 'NON-KIVA' end as Location
from icqa_process_locations
join bins on bins.bin_id = icqa_process_locations.scannable_id
inner join icqa_processes on icqa_processes.icqa_process_id = icqa_process_locations.icqa_process_id
inner join icqa_process_properties on icqa_processes.icqa_process_id = icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_id
--inner join icqa_count_attempts on icqa_count_attempts.icqa_count_attempt_id = icqa_process_locations.icqa_count_attempt_id
where icqa_process_locations.icqa_count_attempt_id is NULL 
     and icqa_processes.process_status = ('Active')     
     and icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_property_value in ('CycleCount', 'SimpleBinCount')
group by CASE when bin_type_name = '14-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')  
    when bin_type_name = '18-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
    when bin_type_name = '24-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
    when bin_type_name = '30-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
    when bin_type_name = '34-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')  
    when bin_type_name = '48-KIVA-DEEP' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
    when bin_type_name = '48-KIVA-XL' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
    when bin_type_name = '78-KIVA-TALL' then ('KIVA-SHELF')
    when bin_type_name = 'PALLET-SINGLE' and usage = '1024' then ('KIVA-PALLET')  
    else 'NON-KIVA' end, bin_level, bin_module, icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_property_value
order by icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_property_value, Location))
SELECT Count_Type || Location,
       SUM(CASE when "Mod" = 'dz-P-1A' THEN Remaining_Counts else 0 END ) AS "P-1-A",
       SUM(CASE when "Mod" = 'dz-P-2A' THEN Remaining_Counts else 0 END ) AS "P-2-A",
       SUM(CASE when "Mod" = 'dz-R-1T' THEN Remaining_Counts else 0 END ) AS "R-1-T",
       SUM(CASE when "Mod" = 'dz-R-1F' THEN Remaining_Counts else 0 END ) AS "R-1-F",
       SUM(CASE when "Mod" = 'dz-R-1O' THEN Remaining_Counts else 0 END ) AS "R-1-O",
       SUM(CASE when "Mod" = 'dz-P-1B' THEN Remaining_Counts else 0 END ) AS "P-1-B",
       SUM(CASE when "Mod" = 'dz-P-1D' THEN Remaining_Counts else 0 END ) AS "P-1-D"
FROM   qry
GROUP BY Count_Type || Location;
```

And the output is this(ALMOST THERE!):

[image]

But, it is producing Zero's When I tried to add type. Before I added the types it worked fine, but I may have missed syntax somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Any chance you can create a sql fiddle with your tables and some sample data?

Comment: What @bluefeet you don't want to do that? :)

Comment: SQL Developer 3.2.20.09.87, and I'll check out sqlfiddle and see if I can make one. I haven't used sql fiddle before.

Comment: @Spartacus38 this is the version of your client tool. bluefeet mean the Oracle server version.

Comment: Whooaaahohoho! Hold on a minute there guy. March 1983: Oracle Database is rewritten in C for portability and Oracle version 3 is released. This might be part of your problem. Your database software is older than I am by three years. I think it might be time to upgrade.

Comment: Theese guys `P-1-A, P-2-A, R-1-T` are fixed or dynamic? I mean can have much more or it is a limited? If it is dynamic, you can only do this through a procedure if it is limited it can be done with just a query. Big query it seems.

Comment: Yes, P-1-A, P-2-A, R-1-T, R-1-F, R-1-O, P-1-B, P-1-D will be fixed.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I do not our Oracle Server version. I am on the DEEEP client end. I'll see if I can find that out.

Comment: @Spartacus38 run this query: `select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter = 'NLS_RDBMS_VERSION`

Comment: Where do you get `SBC - KIVA Shelf` or `CC - KIVA Pallet` from? I understand that you can abbreviate `SimpleBinCount` to `SBC` and `CycleCount` to `CC` but there appears to be no reference to the rest of the string.

Comment: @MT0 we can ignore the KIVA part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7cba7/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( "mod", "floor", "Remaining Counts", CountType ) AS
          SELECT 'dz-P-1A', 1,    37, 'CycleCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-P-1D', 1,   321, 'CycleCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-P-1T', 1,    16, 'CycleCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-P-2A', 2,    25, 'CycleCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-R-1T', 1,  3318, 'CycleCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-P-1A', 1,  6351, 'SimpleBinCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-P-1D', 1,   121, 'SimpleBinCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-P-2A', 2, 12638, 'SimpleBinCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-R-1F', 1,    68, 'SimpleBinCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-R-1O', 1,    47, 'SimpleBinCount' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dz-R-1T', 1,  2051, 'SimpleBinCount' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

PIVOT using `SUM( CASE ... )` statements:

```
SELECT CountType,
       SUM( CASE "mod" WHEN 'dz-P-1A' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-1-A",
       SUM( CASE "mod" WHEN 'dz-P-2A' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-2-A",
       SUM( CASE "mod" WHEN 'dz-R-1T' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "R-1-T",
       SUM( CASE "mod" WHEN 'dz-R-1F' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "R-1-F",
       SUM( CASE "mod" WHEN 'dz-R-1O' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "R-1-O",
       SUM( CASE "mod" WHEN 'dz-P-1B' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-1-B",
       SUM( CASE "mod" WHEN 'dz-P-1D' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-1-D"
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY CountType
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7cba7/5/0)**:

```
|      COUNTTYPE | P-1-A | P-2-A | R-1-T |  R-1-F |  R-1-O |  P-1-B | P-1-D |
|----------------|-------|-------|-------|--------|--------|--------|-------|
| SimpleBinCount |  6351 | 12638 |  2051 |     68 |     47 | (null) |   121 |
|     CycleCount |    37 |    25 |  3318 | (null) | (null) | (null) |   321 |
```

**Query 2**:

Using PIVOT transposition:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT SUBSTR( "mod", 4 ) AS "mod",
          "Remaining Counts",
          CountType
   FROM   tbl t
)
PIVOT
(
   SUM("Remaining Counts")
   FOR "mod" IN ( 'P-1A', 'P-2A', 'R-1T', 'R-1F', 'R-1O', 'P-1B', 'P-1D' )
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7cba7/5/1)**:

```
|      COUNTTYPE | 'P-1A' | 'P-2A' | 'R-1T' | 'R-1F' | 'R-1O' | 'P-1B' | 'P-1D' |
|----------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| SimpleBinCount |   6351 |  12638 |   2051 |     68 |     47 | (null) |    121 |
|     CycleCount |     37 |     25 |   3318 | (null) | (null) | (null) |    321 |
```

**Edit - Wrapping your query:**

```
WITH qry AS (
  select drop_zone_id as "Mod", 
      bin_level as "Floor",
      icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_property_value as "Count Type",
      count(*) as "Remaining Counts",    
      concat(drop_zone_id, icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_property_value) as "Unique",
      to_char(sysdate,'hh:mi:ssam') as "Time Last Updated",
      to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY') as "Date Last Updated"
  from icqa_process_locations 
      inner join icqa_processes on icqa_processes.icqa_process_id = icqa_process_locations.icqa_process_id
      inner join icqa_process_properties on icqa_processes.icqa_process_id = icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_id
      inner join bins on bins.bin_id = icqa_process_locations.scannable_id
  where icqa_count_attempt_id is NULL and icqa_processes.process_status = ('Active')
      and drop_zone_id not like 'dz-R-1B' and drop_zone_id not like 'dz-P-1Z' and drop_zone_id not like 'dz-P-EACH_1'
      and icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_property_value in ('CycleCount', 'SimpleBinCount') 
  group by icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_property_value, bin_level, drop_zone_id
  order by icqa_process_properties.icqa_process_property_value, drop_zone_id
)
SELECT "Count Type",
       SUM( CASE "Mod" WHEN 'dz-P-1A' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-1-A",
       SUM( CASE "Mod" WHEN 'dz-P-2A' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-2-A",
       SUM( CASE "Mod" WHEN 'dz-R-1T' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "R-1-T",
       SUM( CASE "Mod" WHEN 'dz-R-1F' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "R-1-F",
       SUM( CASE "Mod" WHEN 'dz-R-1O' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "R-1-O",
       SUM( CASE "Mod" WHEN 'dz-P-1B' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-1-B",
       SUM( CASE "Mod" WHEN 'dz-P-1D' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-1-D"
FROM   qry
GROUP BY "Count Type";
```

Comment: this looks exactly like how I want, and doesn't seem complicated at all, BUT is there a way to do it without creating a new table? Currently our access to the DB is Read-Only. And Will it work with dynamic data?

Comment: Just wrap your query in a `WITH` statement to create a named sub-query and then reference it in place of a table - like: `WITH qry AS ( ... <INSERT YOUR QUERY HERE> ... ) SELECT CountType,
       SUM( CASE "mod" WHEN 'dz-P-1A' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-1-A", ... SUM( CASE "mod" WHEN 'dz-P-1D' THEN "Remaining Counts" END ) AS "P-1-D" FROM   qry GROUP BY CountType`

Comment: Okay, let me see what I can do thanks. On the <INSERT YOUR QUERY HERE> is that my original query or your addition?

Comment: See my edit for an example. I don't have any tables/data so the edit is untested but you (hopefully) get the principle.

Comment: Updated my question with my new result, I'm almost there!

Comment: Can you post an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) with the table definitions, some sample data and your current query? It would make it a lot easier to see what is going on.

Comment: I will try. Haven't used SQL fiddle, I posted my sample data, and query. But, I'll attempt to mess with fiddle.

Comment: Basically @MT0 yours works great, but I wanted to add another data next to Cycle and Simple. I think I just got it too messy, to see where I'm at.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PLSQL in your application then "user-defined aggregate functions" may be a good way to go. I have found that it provides a nice way to encapsulate transpose functionality and performs very well. I wrote one recently that took massive amounts of interval data (rows) and pivoted them into columns of interval (1-24) by day (rows). It did take a good amount of coding, but I found that the code was clear and easy to maintain.

Here is a link to a list of string aggregation techniques available in Oracle. One of them uses a user_defined function. You essentially do the same things, but return a PLSQL collection of columns instead of an aggregated string:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#user_defined_aggregate_function

I also liked the user-defined aggregate function due to the way Oracle handles the parallellization for performance. Here is more doc in Oracle 11g:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dciaggfns.htm