# SQL pivot unpivot query

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

I don't have much experience with pivot/unpivot and could use some help.  I have a SQL query with data as :

```
Category Account   Name           Value
001      1234     BALANCE_01      800
001      1234     BALANCE_02      1000
001      1234     BALANCE_03      1500
001      4567     BALANCE_01      900
001      4567     BALANCE_02      1200
001      4567     BALANCE_03      800
```

I need it to appear as:

```
Category Account   BALANCE_01  BALANCE_02  BALANCE_03
001       1234       800         1000         1500
001       4567       900         1200         800
```

How do I do this?

Thanks,
Marcie

Comment: This link may prove as some assistance:  https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Comment: Please tag your dbms.

Comment: [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551262/oracle-sql-pivot-table) - 
[Sql-Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745076/5817001) - 
[MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: What is expected result, if your table also have another row with values: `001, 4567, BALANCE_02, 1300` ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to do this is by using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Category,
       Account,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'BALANCE_01' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS BALANCE_01,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'BALANCE_02' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS BALANCE_02,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'BALANCE_03' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) AS BALANCE_03
FROM Table
GROUP BY Category, Account
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just just a group by

```
SELECT Category, Account, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN NAME='BALANCE_1' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS BALANCE_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NAME='BALANCE_2' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS BALANCE_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NAME='BALANCE_3' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS BALANCE_3
FROM Your_Table_You_Did_Not_Name
GROUP BY Category, Account
```

Note, if you have more than one row with the same Category, Account and Name this will fail -- but you don't tell us how to handle that.